# Is everything on $\mathbb R^2$ coplanar?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I would think so, but some places there seems to be indication that $\mathbb R^2$ can have several planes. I kind of thought of $\mathbb R^2$ as one giant plane, and figured everything on it would be coplanar. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plane always has two dimensions, and thus there is a basis of two independent vectors, both in $\mathbb R^2$. Because every pair of independent vectors is a basis of $\mathbb R^2$, we now see that the basis of the plane is also a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Thus, the plane coincides with the space $\mathbb R^2$.

Thus, everything in $\mathbb R^2$ is coplanar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ lies on the same $2$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-linear subspace (namely the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$) and so is a coplanar set by definition.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers said. However, if you consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a vector space of $\mathbb{Q}$ or some other field between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, things get much more entertaining.